# php array function in class

Tags: php, arrays, class

I cant get this script to work, $users should hold the array data we take out of the database but it doesnt seem to work. Can anyone tell us what we are doing wrong? i posted the script bellow.

*added*

$users has to stay static becaus it gets used again later on in the script (this is just a small part)

$user1 does get the right data it just doesnt get passed on to $users

added

this is the intire script hope that helps

---

```
<?php


class SingleSignOn_Server
{

public $links_path;

protected $started=false;

protected static $brokers = array(
    'FGPostbus' => array('secret'=>"FGPostbus123"),
);

protected static $users = array();

public function query_personen(){

mysql_connect('host','user','pass')  or die("Kan helaas geen verbinding maken" . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('db') or die("Kan geen database selecteren");
$sql = mysql_query('select p_gebruikersnaam, p_wachtwoord, p_id, p_md5 FROM personen');

    while ($row_user = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
          self::$users[] = $row_user;
    }

}

protected $broker = null;


public function __construct()
{
    if (!function_exists('symlink')) $this->links_path = sys_get_temp_dir();
}


protected function sessionStart()
{
    if ($this->started) return;
    $this->started = true;

    $matches = null;
    if (isset($_REQUEST[session_name()]) && preg_match('/^SSO-(\w*+)-(\w*+)-([a-z0-9]*+)$/', $_REQUEST[session_name()], $matches)) {
        $sid = $_REQUEST[session_name()];

        if (isset($this->links_path) && file_exists("{$this->links_path}/$sid")) {
            session_id(file_get_contents("{$this->links_path}/$sid"));
            session_start();
            setcookie(session_name(), "", 1);
        } else {
            session_start();
        }

        if (!isset($_SESSION['client_addr'])) {
            session_destroy();
            $this->fail("Not attached");
        }

        if ($this->generateSessionId($matches[1], $matches[2], $_SESSION['client_addr']) != $sid) {
            session_destroy();

            $this->fail("Invalid session id");
        }

        $this->broker = $matches[1];
        return;
    }

    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['client_addr']) && $_SESSION['client_addr'] != $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) session_regenerate_id(true);
    if (!isset($_SESSION['client_addr'])) $_SESSION['client_addr'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}


protected function generateSessionId($broker, $token, $client_addr=null)
{
    if (!isset(self::$brokers[$broker])) return null;

    if (!isset($client_addr)) $client_addr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    return "SSO-{$broker}-{$token}-" . md5('session' . $token . $client_addr . self::$brokers[$broker]['secret']);
}


protected function generateAttachChecksum($broker, $token)
{
    if (!isset(self::$brokers[$broker])) return null;
    return md5('attach' . $token . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . self::$brokers[$broker]['secret']);
}


public function login()
{
    $this->sessionStart();

    if (empty($_POST['p_gebruikersnaam'])) $this->failLogin("No user specified");
    if (empty($_POST['p_wachtwoord'])) $this->failLogin("No password specified");


    if (!isset(self::$users[$_POST['p_gebruikersnaam']]) || self::$users[$_POST['p_gebruikersnaam']]['p_wachtwoord'] != md5($_POST['p_wachtwoord'])) $this->failLogin("Incorrect credentials");

    $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['p_gebruikersnaam'];
    $this->info();
}


public function logout()
{
    $this->sessionStart();
    unset($_SESSION['user']);
    echo 1;
}


public function attach()
{
    $this->sessionStart();

    if (empty($_REQUEST['broker'])) $this->fail("No broker specified");
    if (empty($_REQUEST['token'])) $this->fail("No token specified");
    if (empty($_REQUEST['checksum']) || $this->generateAttachChecksum($_REQUEST['broker'], $_REQUEST['token']) != $_REQUEST['checksum']) $this->fail("Invalid checksum");

    if (!isset($this->links_path)) {
        $link = (session_save_path() ? session_save_path() : sys_get_temp_dir()) . "/sess_" . $this->generateSessionId($_REQUEST['broker'], $_REQUEST['token']);
        if (!file_exists($link)) $attached = symlink('sess_' . session_id(), $link);
        if (!$attached) trigger_error("Failed to attach; Symlink wasn't created.", E_USER_ERROR);
    } else {
        $link = "{$this->links_path}/" . $this->generateSessionId($_REQUEST['broker'], $_REQUEST['token']);
        if (!file_exists($link)) $attached = file_put_contents($link, session_id());
        if (!$attached) trigger_error("Failed to attach; Link file wasn't created.", E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    if (isset($_REQUEST['redirect'])) {
        header("Location: " . $_REQUEST['redirect'], true, 307);
        exit;        
    }


    header("Content-Type: image/png");
    readfile("empty.png");
}

public function info()
{
    $this->sessionStart();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) $this->failLogin("Not logged in");

    header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8');
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>', "\n";       
    echo '<user identity="' . htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['user'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . '">';
    echo '  <p_id>' . htmlspecialchars(self::$users[$_SESSION['user']]['p_id'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . '</p_id>'; 
    echo '  <p_md5>' . htmlspecialchars(self::$users[$_SESSION['user']]['p_md5'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . '</p_md5>';        
    echo '</user>';
}



protected function fail($message)
{
    header("HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable");
    echo $message;
    exit;
}


protected function failLogin($message)
{
    header("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized");
    echo $message;
    exit;
}
}


if (realpath($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]) == realpath(__FILE__) && isset($_GET['cmd']))     {
$ctl = new SingleSignOn_Server();
$ctl->$_GET['cmd']();
}
```

Comment: Okay, what does "doesn't work" mean? Does your query work? Does it iterate trough results?

Comment: Are you even consuming your class? No sense writing blueprints if you don't build the building!

Comment: Please define doesnt seem to work. What is the result?

Comment: it doesnt seem to put the data in $users, sinds we are trying to use it again later on in the script and its empy then

Comment: Fetching the complete table data into a php hash as a lookup seems ...odd. Are you absolutely sure this is the right approach in your case?

Comment: its just a test for now it will be only one row in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very least you probably want to:

```
 self::$users[] = $users1[$row_user['p_gebruikersnaam']] = $row_user;
```

Since as is you where replacing the record every time and keeping only one.

Answer (score 0):

You're building an array as a property of an object, but not using an instance of the object. You need to build a new instance (`$usersObject = new ObjectName;`), drop the `static` keywords, and instead of `self::`, use `$this->`. You also need square brackets after `self::$users`, like this: `self::$users[]`.

Comment: can you explain the "you need to build a new instance ($usersObject = new ObjectName;)," a bit more?

Comment: + $users has to be static cos it gets used again later on

Comment: Properties don't need to be static to be reused later. All that `static` does is allow you to access a property or method without instantiating the class.

Comment: gives me a errors when i dont use static, i put the whole script up

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this `self::$users = $users1[$row_user['p_gebruikersnaam']] = $row_user;` be:

```
array_push($this->users, $row_user)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put directly the result into the array:

```
while (false === ($row_user = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_ASSOC)))
    self::$users[$row_user['p_gebruikersnaam']] = $row_user;
```

Comment: still seems that $users stays empty doing it like this

Comment: no errors at all, yea when i print_r $users1 it shows the array as it should.

i could post the whole script if that would help

Comment: how and when do you access $users?